# Where SBT compiler analysis files are stored during IntelliJ incremental compilation?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, intellij-13

In IntelliJ there is option to use sbt for incremental compilation:

[image: Scala settings]
.

Normally during incremental compilation sbt and zinc creates analysis files which are later used to determine what changed.
That files starts with "format version:" string.

Does anyone know where that files are stored in IntelliJ?
Or if they are stored anywhere at all? I wasn't able to locate them.

Comment: Are you sure "use sbt for incremental compilation" does not use sbt default path? e.g <project-dir>/target/streams/compile/incCompileSetup/$global/streams/

Comment: Unluckily that is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Just have a painful lookup on Mac, but I am not sure whether it's what you want. Anyway, just write it here in case it helps.

Locate IntelliJ home holder, open **`idea.properties`**, you will find config like:

```
idea.system.path=${idea.home}/.IntelliJIdea/system
```

So on my mac, I just go into the system folder like the following

```
cd /Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ 14\ CE.app/Contents/.IntelliJIdea/system/
```

There are two folders in system **`LocalHistory`** and **`caches`** which I think are possible candidates for detecting what you want.

Besides, this may also help, [Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206827437-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs) and [External Builder API and Plugins](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/reference_guide/frameworks_and_external_apis/external_builder_api.html).

Comment: Thanks, I already checked that directories. Yes, there are cache files there, but looks like they are internal IntelliJ caches. I wasn't able to find sbt analysis cache there.